# What mistake did I do in the code that gives me "False" as answer to all the cases?

Tags: python-3.x

I just started learning programming on my own. I am trying to solve the following practice problem on codingbat.com. Logic-2 > make_bricks

> We want to make a row of bricks that is goal inches long. We have a number of small bricks (1 inch each) and big bricks (5 inches each). Return True if it is possible to make the goal by choosing from the given bricks. This is a little harder than it looks and can be done without any loops. See also: Introduction to MakeBricks

```
make_bricks(3, 1, 8) → True  
make_bricks(3, 1, 9) → False  
make_bricks(3, 2, 10) → True
```

The following is my solution. It gives "False" as a result for every test case I tried! What mistake did I do?

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
    small_len = 1 
    big_len = 5
    count_big = 0
    count_small = 0

    #Taking care of exceptional cases where no detailed calculations are required.
    if (big_len == goal) or (small_len == goal):
        return True

    elif small_len > goal: 
        return False 

    elif big_len > goal: 
        for i in range(1,small+1): 
            if (small_len * i) < goal: 
                count_small += 1
        if (small_len * count_small) == goal:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    # Taking care of all the other cases
    else:
        # Counting number of bigger bricks required
        for i in range(1,big+1):
            if (big_len * i) < goal:
                count_big += 1

        # Counting number of smaller bricks required
        for i in range(1,small+1):
            if ((big_len * count_big) + (small_len * i)) < goal:
                count_small += 1

        if ((big_len * count_big) + (small_len * count_small)) == goal:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Just in case you want to take a look at a [good solution](https://github.com/diezguerra/codingbat-python-solutions/blob/654267baf30b736598eb22a4bfa4667ba2dc2c3d/logic-2.py#L1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some mismatch relational operators, you have used `<` operator instead of `<=` operator.

Due to this logical mismatch your code was not executing for last brick required.

I have edited your code at some points here:

```py
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
    small_len = 1 
    big_len = 5
    count_big = 0
    count_small = 0

    #Taking care of exceptional cases where no detailed calculations are required.
    if (big_len == goal) or (small_len == goal):
        return True

    elif small_len > goal: 
        return False 

    elif big_len > goal: 
        for i in range(1,small+1): 
            if (small_len * i) <= goal: 
                count_small += 1
        if (small_len * count_small) == goal:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    # Taking care of all the other cases
    else:
        print("else running")
        # Counting number of bigger bricks required
        for i in range(1,big+1):
            if (big_len * i) <= goal:
                count_big += 1

        print("big brick used {}".format(count_big))
        # Counting number of smaller bricks required
        for i in range(1,small+1):
            if ((big_len * count_big) + (small_len * i)) <= goal:
                count_small += 1

        print("small brick used {}".format(count_small))
        if ((big_len * count_big) + (small_len * count_small)) == goal:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the purpose of for_loop here. A simple ifelse statements:

```
def make_bricks(ones, fives, length):
    total_fives = 5 * fives
    fives_needed = length // 5
    if ones>=length or length%5 ==0 and  total_fives >=length: return True
    elif fives_needed<=fives and (length - fives_needed * 5)<=ones: return True
    elif fives_needed>fives and total_fives + ones >= length: return True
    else: return False


make_bricks(3, 1, 8)
 True

make_bricks(3, 1, 9)
 False

make_bricks(3, 2, 10)
 True
```